# Python - How is it possible to keep a trailing space when returning a string?

Tags: python, string, return, space

Is there a way to keep a trailing space after a string when returning it?

For example I have the value '6 '. If I return it from a class back into my main code it strips the space off of the end.

If you really need to know why:
The class looks at a number and then adds the scientific abbreviation, so it works great if converting .005 to "5 m" and then the units later added on make it "5 mV", but if I just have 5, it tries to return "5 " but only returns "5" making it look like "5V" which is inconsistent.

EDIT: Sorry everyone, but it was actually a really stupid error on my part. I had .strip() placed on the command that calls the class (). I was calling the python debugger *in* the class and watching it return everything, but using the debugger in manner never actually shows the line of code that calls class. It's was really obvious once I saw it.

Comment: Could you show us some code demonstrating this behavior?

Comment: It's probably better to return a number and then use some form of string formatting instead of what you're attempting to do now.

Comment: Problem was inexistent, close question?

Comment: Voting to close as OP has not responded to requests for followup.

Comment: @Steven That's a bit harsh, giving less than an hour to respond to followup requests. Wow.

Comment: @corsiKa:  Those requests were made less than 60 seconds after the question was posted.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have to do anything. This code prints "6 m" for example:

```
def foo():
    return "6 "

print foo() + "m"
```

Output

```
6 m
```